# How to retrieve more than 200 tweets

Tags: php, twitter

I would like to know how to retrieve more than 200 tweets from a twitter page. I know its limited to 200 but read you can retrieve more,Im using php and using this following line of code to get the 200 tweets

```
  $xmldata = 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/BBCNews.xml?count=200';
```

Could someone show me some example code in how to do this?

thanks

Comment: http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/BBCNews.xml?count=400

Comment: What are you asking? How to parse an XML file, or how to modify your URL to request more data? And what have you tried?

Comment: how to modify url to request more data as 200 is the limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the twitter API you can only get up to 200 posts per page.  You would have to add a &page=x to get the page of tweets (there is a hard limit of 3200 posts)

View the api documentation here

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

An example of the api call for json would be

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=200&page=2
```

and an example for the xml call would be

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=true&screen_name=twitterapi&count=200&page=2
```

So what i would suggest is if you want to get all 3200 posts is to set up the script in a function to change the page number each time

Comment: Please see the posts again for the edit.  There is a limit of 200 posts per page... you must add page=XX to the url

Comment: hey have tried to do that before and wasnt able to do it,   what do you mean by "in a look"? thanks

Comment: Sorry... it was "in a function" meaning so you can loop through each page.  Also check my sample calls as they are working examples