# How to set page parameter twitter api user timeline

Tags: twitter, python-twitter, twitterapi-python, http-parameters

How can I get the 3200 most recent tweets from a users timeline [as documented](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline)?

I know I can only get 200 tweets per request. I [want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623412/how-to-retrieve-more-than-200-tweets) to use the [page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/guides/working-with-timelines) parameter, but the page parameter is no longer present in the current documentation. It [did contain](http://web.archive.org/web/20120807205224/https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline) the optional page parameter originally but

> will soon cease to be functional

Also I work with the python-twitter library and the `GetUserTimeline` function from the API object has no optional page parameter.

Maybe this has something to do with the [switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916539/simplest-php-example-for-retrieving-user-timeline-with-twitter-api-version-1-1) from Twitter API v1.0 to v1.1?

Comment: I guess I just have to use the `max_id` parameter ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Using `max_id` is correct.